Why is πλοῦτος sometimes neuter?
I was reading some of the letters of St. Paul recently and noticed that πλοῦτος is sometimes neuter, e.g. Ephesians 1:7:

. . . ἐν ᾧ ἔχομεν τὴν ἀπολύτρωσιν διὰ τοῦ αἵματος αὐτοῦ, τὴν ἄφεσιν τῶν παραπτωμάτων, κατὰ τὸ πλοῦτος τῆς χάριτος αὐτοῦ. . . .

(See also Col 2:2; Col 1:27)
In the very same chapter, though, Paul also uses the masculine article:

. . . εἰς τὸ εἰδέναι ὑμᾶς τίς ἐστιν ἡ ἐλπὶς τῆς κλήσεως αὐτοῦ, τίς ὁ πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης τῆς κληρονομίας αὐτοῦ ἐν τοῖς ἁγίοις. . . .

(See also Rom 9:23)
LSJ mentions the variation, but doesn't say anything about a cause of this variant form or difference in meaning. I also noticed that the apparatus criticus often (always?) lists a variant reading with a masculine article, which might indicate that early scribes also saw it as a lectio difficilior.
What is the reason for these two different forms in the works of Paul? Is it confined to his works, or do we find similar variation in other authors?

There are 22 instances of πλοῦτος in the NT, and it's unambiguously masculine in twelve, neuter in eight, and impossible to determine in two (both in Romans 11:12, nominatives with no article; interesting that they're both predicates where the subject is neuter, though). All instances of clearly neuter πλοῦτος also have manuscripts that show a masculine.
Since πλοῦτος is unusual in being an abstract noun that's masculine (there are a few others like it, like  βίοτος, νόστος, but most abstract nouns are feminine or neuter) but also superficially looks like a neuter s-stem (γένος &c.), I'd go ahead and guess that all of the instances of neuter πλοῦτος are just errors. The fact that, as you noted, Ephesians has one masculine πλοῦτος (1:18: "ὁ πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης") and four neuter ones (including 3:16: "τὸ πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης") with no apparent difference in meaning seems to confirm no point is being made by choosing one over the other.
Obviously a good philologist would preserve the lectio difficilior, but it's worth noting that the Greek Orthodox Church corrects the neuters to masculines in almost every case.

Do you think the "errors" come from St. Paul or from the earliest manuscripts? (Or perhaps it is impossible to say?)

Re determining the gender, it looks like the only cases are nominative, accusative, and genitive. In the case of the genitive, I think you can rule out it being neuter, since the form would be different (as LSJ notes): τοῦ πλούτεος.

@brianpck The NT manuscript tradition isn't my speciality, but it seems the ones that have neuters tend to be older, and it's mostly Byzantine manuscripts that change neuters to masculines. In general you would expect scribes who speak the language to correct errors of this sort rather than introduce them (and scribes who don't know Greek wouldn't be able to introduce them), so I'd say they're original. Also, you're absolutely right about the genitive, of course; brain fart on my part.

Did you mean to say that it is unusual for abstract nouns to be masculine? For many are feminine.

@Cerberus Feminines are just a special kind of neuter anyway.

@Cairnarvon: I thought it was the other way around, neuter plural is really a kind of feminine?

@Cerberus Last I heard, the feminine developed from the neuter plural. Hittite only has animate and inanimate, and the inanimate plural in the nominate and accusative ends in -a.

Re MSS tradition: the GNT doesn't even list a variant at Col. 1.27, meaning they're sure the neuter is as early as the earliest manuscripts. I doubt it's a scribal change, unless the manuscripts went through a very narrow bottleneck.

FWIW, Modern Greek has adopted the plural, τα πλούτη, from the neuter, as it largely follows NT choices.

@CosmasZachos That feels more like a collective construction to me than a plural downstream from the NT neuter singular; it's possible it's an analogical creation that happened for the same reason but independently from the NT neuter. I don't have access to a queryable Byzantine corpus to prove it, though.
